# How to return a list of clusters using Louvain in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I want to create an array with all the nodes in each cluster using the Louvain algorithm in this format:

```
clusters = [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 24, 27, 31, 33, 35, 46, 47, 48, 49, 54, 58, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 90, 91, 93, 98, 103, 104, 106, 107, 115, 116, 117, 119, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 129, 132, 137, 141, 148, 150, 151, 152, 154, 160, 162, 164, 165, 168, 171, 183, 185, 190, 193, 204, 211, 215, 216, 218, 227, 231, 233, 235, 238, 239], [26, 40, 74, 79, 158, 177, 195, 203, 225, 230], [179, 0, 1, 3, 9, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 29, 34, 36, 41, 45, 52, 56, 59, 60, 61, 62, 73, 78, 88, 95, 100, 101, 102, 109, 112, 120, 133, 135, 138, 145, 146, 149, 155, 156, 163, 170, 172, 173, 175, 181, 184, 186, 191, 192, 194, 198, 202, 205, 207, 208, 210, 212, 223, 226, 229, 234, 237, 240, 241, 220, 178, 232], [4, 5, 6, 8, 28, 37, 39, 71, 72, 92, 94, 127, 147, 157, 169, 180, 182, 187, 209, 219, 228], [2, 7, 10, 11, 12, 23, 30, 32, 38, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 53, 55, 57, 67, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 83, 89, 96, 97, 99, 105, 108, 110, 111, 113, 114, 118, 126, 128, 130, 131, 134, 136, 139, 140, 142, 143, 144, 153, 159, 161, 166, 167, 174, 176, 188, 189, 196, 197, 199, 200, 201, 206, 213, 214, 217, 221, 222, 224, 236]]
```

For this purpose i have created the following code in python:

```
    import community as community_louvain
    import networkx as nx
    import networkx.algorithms.community as nx_comm
    import copy
    
    G = nx.read_edgelist(r"C:\Users\secret\Desktop\graph-edges.txt", create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype=int)
    
    
    def compute_clustering(G, required_number_of_clusters, min_size_of_clusters, min_modularity, weight=None):
        i = 0.1
        while i <= 1:
            partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G, random_state=1500, resolution=i)
            if (max(partition.values())+1) == required_number_of_clusters:
                b = sorted(partition.items())
                c = dict(b)
                labels = []
                for node in c.keys():
                    clusterz = c[node]
                    labels.append(clusterz)
                num_of_nodes = len(labels)
                num_of_clusters = len(set(labels))
                clusters = []
                for i in range(num_of_clusters):
                    clusters.append(list())
                for i in range(num_of_nodes):
                    cluster_id = labels[i]
                    clusters[cluster_id].append(i)
                lc = len(clusters)
                temp = []
                cluster = copy.deepcopy(clusters)
                for i in range(lc):
                    for j in range(len(clusters[i])):
                        if len(cluster[i]) > min_size_of_clusters:
                            m = nx_comm.modularity(G, cluster)
                            temp.append(cluster[i][0])
                            cluster[i].remove(cluster[i][0])
                            count = 0
                            for w in range(len(clusters)):
                                if w != i:
                                    cluster[w].append(temp[0])
                                    if nx_comm.modularity(G, cluster) > m:
                                        temp.remove(temp[0])
                                        break
                                    else:
                                        cluster[w].remove(temp[0])
                                        count = count + 1
                                        if count == len(clusters) - 1:
                                            cluster[i].append(temp[0])
                                            temp.remove(temp[0])
                                            break
                mod = nx_comm.modularity(G, cluster)
                if mod > min_modularity:
                    print(mod)
                    return cluster
            else:
                i = i+0.1
    
    
    compute_clustering(G, 5, 7, 0.13, weight='weight')
```

The graph-edges.txt is a weighted graph that is too big to post here but here is a portion of it:

```
0 45 {'weight': 0.3488372093023256}
0 33 {'weight': 0.11627906976744186}
0 71 {'weight': 0.046511627906976744}
0 78 {'weight': 0.37209302325581395}
0 150 {'weight': 0.09302325581395349}
...
(about 29.000 lines of data)
```

The problem is that this code doesnt return the list of clusters i want, so I am hoping there is a different way to produce it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `clusters`? It is not the cluster assignment. So is it cluster sizes? But what are all those conditions below? I think you need to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Also, at least one issue is your reuse of the variable `i`.

Comment: A final piece of unsolicited advice: if you enjoy programming, you should probably read Robert Martin's Clean Code. It is a fantastic book, you can find a pdf online, and you are probably in the top 1% of people that would benefit most from reading it.